# SDK or API support for Sony RX0

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm hoping to develop custom photo booth software that will work with the upcoming Sony RX0. Are there any development tools that will work with the RX0 camera at launch?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is valid, but should be reworded as "Does the RX0 support the Sony Remote API"?

The Remote API was last updated March 7, 2016.

The Android Playmemories APP has been updated with RX0 support, however that does not confirm 100% that the RX0 uses the Remote API.

Can someone from Sony confirm support?

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the question I was trying to ask. Not sure why the reflexive response from @GrumpyCrouton

Still hoping someone can answer this for me.